# Removing padding in a <li> without disturbing the rest of the list

Tags: css, image, dreamweaver, padding

I have a list established as a side bar with the left-padding of 20px.
At the end of my list I am inserting an image and do not want the 20px to affect my image. 
How do I remove the padding for only my image?

I tried to include screenshots but as I am a new user that feature is disabled.

```
#sidebar li {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 20px;
}

<li>
    <h2>Follow</h2>
    <p><img src="../../Desktop/Root/_Images/follow.jpg" width="240" height="76" alt="Follow" /></p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specific rules trump less specific rules in CSS, so any styles you define in:

```
sidebar li img {
```

will override the inherited ones from:

```
sidebar li {
```

Comment: Thank you. I have included the CSS 
#sidebar li img {
padding: 0px;
}
With the image still staying in the same position :/

Comment: Perhaps it's not (directly) the padding that's your problem?  If you use the FIrefox Firebug extension (and other browsers have similar tools) you can inspect your image and see what factors are causing it to be positioned where it is (it will show you the amount of border, margin, padding, and width/height each element has, and you can also check any other CSS property).

Comment: I do use Dreamweavers 'inspect mode' and that's how I found the <li> padding to be the problem. I used Marat's response of off setting my image by -20px but thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ah great.  Just FYI, another way to do it would be to use a negatively positioned relative element (`left: -20px; position: relative;`).  If margin-left works for you no need to change, but if you ever need to have a real margin on that LI you can use the `left` and `position` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a negative offset for `IMG` or `P` to compensate `padding-left`:

```css
IMG {margin-left: -20px; }
```

or reset padding for specific item, e.g. last one:

```css
#sidebar LI:last-child {padding-left: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very new to this and have refrained from asking newbie questions on forums but I could not figure this out! I used your first response as I have no experience with 'last-child', will start learning though! Thank you again.